# Problema con la depuración en geany: el sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado

Tags: c++, gdb

estoy en Windows 10 y tengo Geany en la versión 2.0 con el complemento "Depurador de ámbito: Interfaz relativamente sencilla para GDB." instalado.

Para depurar un programa lo que estoy intentando es compilarlo de la siguiente forma:

`g++ -Wall -g -DTEST --debug -o "pruebas_varias" "pruebas_varias.cpp" (en el directorio: C:\Users\Nombre_usuario\Documents)`

Y después en los menús voy a Depurar->Configurar programa y donde dice "Ejecutable: " pongo "C:\Users\Nombre_usuario\Documents\pruebas_varias.exe" (sin las comillas).

Pero cuando voy a ejecutarlo me salta el error:

**"Error creating process /c/Program Files/Geany/C:\Users\Nombre_usuario\Documents\pruebas_varias.exe, (error 2: El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.)"**

¿alguien sabe que puedo estar haciendo mal? En Ubuntu mate 22.04 lo probé de la misma forma y parece estar funcionado bien.

Comment: Prueba con `g++ -Wall -g -DTEST --debug -o "pruebas_varias.exe" "pruebas_varias.cpp"`

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar y da el mismo error.

Comment: Está creando el ejecutable? Tal vez haya un problema para ubicarlo